# How to edit the rate of flow in system dynamic modelling in anylogic program?

Tags: java, anylogic

I want to change the rate of a flow that is connected to 2 stocks, stock1 and stock2.

If the first stock is empty the rate takes zero and if it is positive (not empty) it takes the default value(2).

The code in the *rate* field:

```
if (stock1 <= 0) {
   0
}
else {
   2
}
```

It gives syntax error.

Thanks.

Comment: Try this: `rate = stock1 <= 0 ? 0 : 2;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that AnyLogic (or Java respectively) expects an expression and a if-then-else is a statement that does not return a value. So you have to use the ternary operator that SMA suggested in his comment which would look like this: `(stock1 <= 0) ? 0 : 2`
This Java language construct is an expression that returns a value depending on a condition.